# Cd into subdirectories using Bash

Tags: shell, sh

[image]I am writing a shell script to cd into subdirectories in a main directory, however I am getting an error that directory does not exists, so when I print out the value of the directory value I see that directory names are listed in a weird way,can someone help me to correct this error.

Code:

```
for d in ./*
        do
                (cd $d && ./example.c) 
        done
```

Output when I do echo $d:

```
./Directory, Test

./Directory, Test1
```

Orignal directory names in the parent directory:

```
Test,Directory
Test1,Directory
```

Comment: What results do you get if you correctly quote the parameter expansion: `cd "$d"`, `echo "$d"`, etc.?

Comment: I changed it but same result

Comment: Can you copy-paste the exact and complete output you get? Avoid transcribing by hand or writing an example that is similar to what you get: Bash is the kind of language where saying "It says no such file or directory" is not helpful, while copy-pasting `: No such file or directory` makes it immediately obvious what the problem is (just because of a leading colon that people normally wouldn't think is important).

Comment: Added image  output

Comment: Hard to see what `./example.c` is supposed to do (if it is in fact a c-source file), it can't be executable...

Comment: That is secondary concern, i can't cd into directories which are there

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l`?